# Does the authorize.net (AIM) API require PCI compliance or any additional certification?

Tags: php, authorize.net, pci-compliance

I was wondering if anyone here has used the authorize.net "[Advanced Integration Method](http://developer.authorize.net/api/aim/)" API.

I've scoured the FAQs on their site, but I can't seem to find a straightforward answer or get through to them at this hour.

I know the API requires SSL (obviously), but does their TOS agreement require PCI compliance or any kind of certification, provided you are not storing credit card numbers? Also, if anyone would happen to know, is there anything in their TOS against using this for an app that stores merchant credential (with explicit merchant permission of course)?

To clarify, on that last part, I'm talking about a SaS application storing merchant id and transaction keys for multiple merchants (same server).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it requires PCI compliance. AIM requires you to collect the user data on your own web server before sen ding it off to Authorize.Net for processing. This means you are handling and transmitting credit card information and therefore must be PCI compliant.

This is not an Authorize.Net requirement, it's a Payment Card Industry requirement. Authorize.Net does not take responsibility for how a merchant handles their payments in-so-far-as they do not violate Authorize.Net's terms of service. So if you're not PCI compliant Authorize.Net doesn't care. But the card issuers do and will raise issues with the merchant if their site is not PCI compliant and using the AIM API.

Comment: even if card information is never stored or retained in any way?

Comment: Yep. PCI covers handling and transmission of information as well

Comment: Should I assume they expect certification and not just compliance? PS: I must say, your reply lag time (14 seconds) is much better than mine (19 days)...

Comment: They're more or less one in the same. But they're rarely proactive about it. Most, if not all, merchant account providers don't do PCI checks and I know the payment gateways don't. I've only ever had to deal with one potential client who actually had someone contact them about not being compliant but they never followed through with us so I don't know if it was a "real" violation or someone just trying to get some money from them (kinda like those SEO companies who tell everyone their site isn't optimized).

Comment: My (bad and unofficial) advice is to use AIM with best practices (code securely, use SSL, etc) and if someone from the Payment Card Industry says you're not PCI compliant *then* find out where you failed compliance and remedy it. The odds are it's just that the server isn't compliant (no firewall, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. One last question -- by-the-book, is there some sort of actual 'certificate' or 'licence' you're expected to obtain/maintain? Or is it basically up to the brands to complain if they find you're doing something obviously insecure?

Comment: There are companies that do PCI certification. I haven't had any clients do it so I don't know exactly how they prove you are PCI compliant but I'm sure they do provide you with something that the PCI considers satisfactory. Typically most companies are reactive (like my advice suggested) as opposed to proactive (being a good net citizen). This is probably half due to cost and half due to ignorance. But either way I don't think any certification will come in handy until someone comes looking for it as I don't know of how to communicate to the powers-that-be that your site is compliant.

Comment: As a side note, PCI compliance is kind of a red herring. It really doesn't mean a site is secure. It just means it meets PCI guidelines which really are just a collection of no-brainer security tips. Yes, it's good to have standards but a lot of people are fooled into believing PCI compliance = safe which just isn't true.

Answer (score 2):

If you use AIM, you're in scope for PCI. Many many developers wishfully think that they won't be in scope if they merely transmit the card data onward to Authorize.net using the AIM api.

All of those developers are wrong under the current PCI rules. Since the card info is transiting your server, a bad guy could break into your server and steal the card info. Doesn't matter how unlikely it is, you're now in the scope of PCI.

To use Authorize.Net and stay out of the PCI Scope, use integration methods SIM or their new [Direct Post Method](http://developer.authorize.net/api/dpm/).  Both keep your server out of scope.

More on this from [Auth.net](http://developer.authorize.net/api/compare/)

Answer (score 1):

The whole PCI compliance initiative is a complete mess and will become unenforceable because there's no real definitive answers.  The few that exist are murky and ambiguous.

The guide clearly says that if you store or transmit sensitive payment data, then you're in scope. You can get out of scope by using a payment tokenization service for storage, and direct posting to a payment gateway for transmission.  Both of these techniques, will keep you out of scope.

The direct posting makes no sense to me.  I don't see how a server post-back step qualifies as transmission, but a direct post to a payment gateway doesn't.  You're sending sensitive data in both cases.  If the sensitive data is received through a secure post-back and it's immediately discarded after sending it to the gateway, then what's the difference?

You'll die laughing when you find out that a web browser doesn't have to be PCI compliant. It can even store payment data locally and transmit it through an unsecured channel!  You could argue that the theft potential is smaller because it's not a public server and it's operated by the user of the credit card.  Regardless, the tiny amount of time where payment data sits on a server to be processed during a post-back should have the same consideration.

Furthermore, browsers can run anywhere including on public kiosks and phones.

Comment: The difference is that when it goes to the merchant, it does not hit your servers. When it goes to your servers, there's a chance it will get saved in the access logs, and then you have to worry about anyone who may potentially have access to those access logs. And anyone who may have access to the credentials for access, etc.

Answer (score -1):

as for the first part of your question..  no, it does not require PCI compliance.  One of the major advantages of using Authorize.net is to offload the PCI compliance to them.  Having said that, using Authorize.net , of course, does not automatically remove any PCI liability from you.

Comment: Would you happen to know if it violates any rules to store merchant credentials?

Comment: clarify please.. your merchant credentials?  whos merchant credentials?

Comment: assuming I'm running an SaS POS/invoicing application (like freshbooks), with merchants as my primary users -- can I store those merchant IDs, etc and use the AIM API, rather than the simplified one that works more like Google Checkout?

Comment: that is an excellent question... can you run charges through Authorize.net on behalf of another merchant.  I dont know the definitive answer for that, but my guess is no.  The reason is... and this is more of an educated guess.. is that Authorize.net stores your merchant info in association with your account.  Its not a one to many relationship.  Many merchants == many accounts in their eyes.  Business.

Comment: ya.. probably a deal they cut with them.  dont be afraid to reach out and contact them.

Comment: -1 This is not true if you use AIM per the current PCI standards since you're transmitting the data to Auth.net. If you use Auth.Net AIM integration, then your software/server is "In Scope" for PCI Compliance. What that entails depends on you and your Card Association via your Merchant Account provider.

Comment: I don't see how this can be a problem. All you need is the merchant login which you provide them.